# Rewrite Rule which takes wildcard characters and add it to the destination page

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, wildcard

I need a rewrite rule which redirects to a subdomain, but takes takes everything from wildcard to the destination page

for example:

if
    https://example.org/product/abcde
is called, the redirect should go to 
    https://new.example.org/product/abcde

What I have already have is:

```
RewriteRule ^/product/(.*)$ https://new.example.org/product [R=301,L]
```

but this Rule "forgets" everything after /product/ in the redirect

Is it possible add the wildcard characters to the new URL?

What I tried is:

```
RewriteRule ^/product/(.*)$ https://new.example.org/product/(.*) [R=301,L]
```

But then the redirect goes to to the URL

```
https://new.example.org/product/(.*)
```

instead of

```
https://new.example.org/product/abcde
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could find a solution, which works perfect for my requirement

```
RewriteRule ^/produkt(.*)(.*) https://new.example.org/produkt$1/$2 [R=301,L]
```

Solutions was found at https://alvinalexander.com/web/apache-redirectmatch-examples-wildcard-301